# ActiveX method with variable parameter list?

Tags: windows, mfc, activex, ocx

I have a DLL that provides functions with a variable parameter list that are defined like

my_func(int var,...)

Depending on how my_func() is called it expectes more or less additional parameters.

Now this DLL has to be wrapped by an MFC-based ActiveX-control. For the method definitions I can find many VT_ and VTS_ defines that wrap to a specific, pre-defined type. But is it possible to have a ActiveX-method with such a variable parameter list too?

If yes: how can it be implemented?

Comment: You could consider a (fixed size) struct/record with all relevant values and just hand that one pointer. Then agree on values/flags to indicate empty fields.
Or alternatively; two variables one of which is a pointer to a struct (with data that applies to a certain scenario) and the other is a identifier for that type of struct. In the windows API, often the struct size is used as a (version) identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is technically possible, by using the `vararg` keyword in the IDL in combination with an argument specified as `SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)`, there is no support for specifying such a method in an MFC ActiveX project. You can do it with ATL instead, but I think this would be an enormous inconvenience just to get the functionality you describe.

Some better choices (in my opinion) would be:

1. Provide specific methods for each of the use cases of your wrapped function.
2. Provide a single method that exposes *all* arguments and add a UINT to set flags depending on which arguments should be used.

My choice would be 1.

Comment: Hm, both solutions are impossible in this case. The variable parameter list originally is a list consisting of a tag (char-array) and a value (depends on the tag and can be char-array, int or pointer). The resulting possible combinations and variants are really huge. So I afraid I have to provide functions that set one tag/value pair per call and an other functions that finishes the list so that it can be used internally. Not very elegant...

Comment: I See - I guess you need some type of Façade pattern here, is it easier to do this in the DLL to make the ActiveX simpler?